# Singleton service inside a class instance

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a class in which I need to use a service but this class needs to be instantiated.

It's like this:

```
class EntrySubject implements ISubject {
    constructor(entry: EntryEntity) {}
}
```

Since I need a service there, I could do this:

```
class EntrySubject implements ISubject {
    constructor(entry: EntryEntity, entryService: EntryService) {}
}
```

And when using this class inside `EntryService` I would just instantiate my class as:

```
const entrySubject = new EntrySubject(entry, this);
```

But in this case, as far as I understand, every new subject instance would have its own EntryService, but what should I do if I want a single instance of EntryService?

Comment: How do you get `EntryEntity`? If it's something injected by Nest, it should be singleton scope already, so you'll have the same `entity` and same `service` for each `Subject`

Comment: Ah, no, `EntryEntity` is just an entity, that's, just a class with the `@Entity` decorator, I just want to pass this entity as a parameter to  `EntrySubject` when it gets instantiated. I'm talking about the second arg in that constructor which is `EntryService` and this service needs to be singleton when I have , say, an array of entrySubjects. I mean something like this: `[new EntrySubject(entry1, this), new EntrySubject(entry2, this)]`.

Comment: Oh, that should be fine then. It should all be the same instance of the `Service` class

Comment: I don't know anything about Nest, but typically a singleton has a static method like `getInstance()` or `instance`.  Is that the case here?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to decorate your EntitySubject, or any other class that you wish to inject, with @Injectable(), and have that class in the 'providers' array of the module. That way, when the constructor has the class in its params, nest will inject a singletone instance of that class.

Please note that when using @Injectable, the default value that is used is @Injectable({scope: DEFAULT}) which means a singletone instance of the class.

For more info on injection scopes visit :
https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes